# RTL problem in angular syncfusion diagram

Tags: angular, diagram, syncfusion

In the Syncfusion official document for angular, there is a guide for RTL and it's simple and straight forward. They say we should add following code to the main component to enable RTL:

```
import { enableRtl } from '@syncfusion/ej2-base';
// Enables Right to left alignment for all controls
enableRtl(true);
```

or for individual component: adding -> enableRtl='true'

```
`<ejs-listview id='sample-list' [dataSource]='data' [fields]='fields' showHeader='true'
    enableRtl='true' headerTitle='Social Media'>
    <ng-template #template let-data="">
    <span class='{{data.class}} icon'><span class='media'>{{data.socialMedia}}</span></span>
    </ng-template>
</ejs-listview> `
```

Now, In my angular project, I use diagram, and RTL is enabled; but the style for text isn't good at all.
I fork diagram demo from official syncfusion document and the link is:
[RTL syncfusion angular diagram](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rsyuwj?file=app.component.ts)

how can I fix it to show text properly?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, in the diagram, we have support to render diagram elements from left to right. We do not have RTL support for our diagram component.